# Wrong output for function that computes the sum of the digits in an integer

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm required to write a function that computes and returns the sum of the digits in an integer.

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    number1=input("Enter a number: ")
    number=list(number1)
    i=0
    while len(number)!=i:
        numbers=[]
        x=int(number[i])
        numbers.append(x)
        number.remove(number[i])

print(numbers)
x=float(sum(numbers))
print(x)

main()
```

The output looks like:

```
Enter a number: 123
[3]
3.0
```

I'm not sure why 1 and 2 aren't in the list, and aren't used to compute the sum... any suggestions?

Comment: It's been answered, but one minor nitpick: change `while len(number)!=i` to `for i in len(number)` and then get rid of the `number.remove` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reinitialize `numbers` *inside the loop*. Don't do that, move that outside of the loop instead:

```
numbers=[]
while len(number)!=i:
    # ...
```

otherwise you end up resetting the list for each and every digit.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much! haha what a silly mistake. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

It's good for you to learn the basics before you try advanced stuff, but just for fun, here is the way an experienced Python coder would solve this problem:

```
def main():
    number1=input("Enter a number: ")  # for Python 2.x, need to use raw_input()
    return float(sum(int(ch) for ch in number1))

x = main()
print(x)
```

We can use the builtin function `sum()` to sum the digit numbers, and we get the digit numbers with a "generator expression" that loops over the string directly while calling `int()`.

This is just a taste of the fun stuff you will be learning soon in Python.  :-)

Comment: @stevaha +1 but you should use raw_input instead of input, this gives TypeError 'int object is not iterable' exception.

Comment: Since the question was tagged "python-3.x" I didn't use `raw_input()`, which is not available in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a more functional way, if you are interested in this kind of programming. It would then look like this:

```
def main():
    number1=input("Enter a number: ")  # for Python 2.x, need to use raw_input()
    return float(sum(map(int, number1))

x = main()
print(x)
```